# Mongodb: how to create multiple indexes on same field?

Tags: mongodb

For example, I created this index:

```
db.test.createIndex({field1:1}, {partialFilterExpression:{field2:{$gt:10}}})
```

Index created successfully. Then I want to create second index:

```
db.test.createIndex({field1:1}, {partialFilterExpression:{field2:{$lte:10}}}
```

But above will give error  `IndexOptionsConflict`, but no error details, only dumps the index object.

I have tested to create such indexes on PostgreSQL and it works. How can I do this in MongoDB?

Comment: You cannot create an index with the same field but different options on MongoDB. See [SERVER-25023](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-25023) for possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth noting that this will most likely be fixed with 4.8 stable release.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-25023

Comment: It's already been fixed in MongoDB 6.0, I checked it.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, a restriction of [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#restrictions):

> ## Restrictions
>
> In MongoDB, you cannot create multiple versions of an index that
> differ only in the options. As such, you cannot create multiple
> partial indexes that differ only by the filter expression.

Right now, you can only do this:

```
db.test.createIndex({field1:1}, {partialFilterExpression:{field2:{$gt:10,$lte:10}}})
```

Or use composite indexes with a placeholder field:

```
db.test.createIndex({field1:1, never_use_this_field1: 1}, {partialFilterExpression:{field2:{$gt:10}}})
db.test.createIndex({field1:1, never_use_this_field2: 1}, {partialFilterExpression:{field2:{$lte:10}}}
```